# Offline download of Google Spreadsheet that saves Google script code as well

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, download

What's an efficient way of making an offline backup of a Google spreadsheet so that it includes its Google script files? It seems that if I use the Download as Microsoft Excel File feature, the downloaded xlsx file does not include any Google script that is part of the spreadsheet.

I saw a post about a command line tool called "Clasp" by Google that can be used but I was hoping to use something that is not so arcane.

Comment: It looks that you are looking for a software recommendation. Unfortunately this type of questions are off-topic here. Try [softwarerecs.se] or the Google Apps Script community (click on "community" link on the sidebar of https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support)

Comment: I use Apps Script API and save backup as ascii text files in JSON format. I can restore entire projects.